# Examples of topologies in which all open sets are countable union of base elements, but the topology itself doesn't have countable bases.

Tags: general-topology, second-countable, sorgenfrey-line

In second countable topology(i.e. has countable bases), obviously all open sets are countable union of base elements. But the inverse seems not true.

The sorgenfrey line $R_l$ seems to be an example. The proof is analogous to [sorgenfrey line is lindelof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183962/how-to-show-r-l-is-lindelof-space) and [sorgenfrey line is T6 perfectly normal](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_Line_is_Perfectly_Normal). Given an open set $U = \bigcup B_\alpha$ for some base elements $B_\alpha \in \mathcal{B}$, partition it into its interior $I$ in the ordinary topology $R$ and $U-I$. Because $R_l$ is finer than the ordinary topology $R$ and $R$ is second countable, $I$ can be written as countable union of base elements both in $R$ and $R_l$ i.e. $I=\bigcup_i (c_i,d_i)$. For $U-I$, each $x \in U-I$ has to belong to a base element $[x, b_x) \subset U$ otherwise if $x \in (a,b) \subset U$, it will be in $I$. Replace $b_x$ with a rational number $b'_x$ by shrinking. For two distinct point $x, y \in U-I$, $[x,b'_x)$ and $[y,b'_y)$ have to be disjoint, otherwise either $x$ or $y$ will be in $I$. Therefore, the elements in $U-I$ is countable. Now, $U = I\bigcup (U-I) = \bigcup_i (c_i, d_i) \bigcup (\bigcup_{x\in U-I} [x, b'_x))$. Hence, all open sets in $R_l$ is countable union of base elements. However, [$R_l$ is not second countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135993/mathbbr-with-the-lower-limit-topology-is-not-second-countable).

Is my proof correct roughly? And I would like more examples of topologies that are not second countable, but in which every open sets are countable union of base elements.

Edit: as the comments mentioned, there is a trivial example that if all open sets are considered base elements, every topology has this property. I think to eliminate this triviality, the original question should be reformulated as

**For every possible collections of bases, all open sets can be written as countable union of bases in this topology, yet the topology is not second countable.**

Clearly, $R_l$ is still valid as an example.

Comment: To add my initial thoughts, a topology in which every open set is compact might be a start point for the example and I do find this type of topology [Noetherian topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian_topological_space). But I just started to learn general topology and can't find any way to modify it to non second-countable.

Comment: Since a topology is a base for itself, every topology has a base with the property that every open set is the union not just of a countable family of base elements, but of a singleton set of base elements.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, True, I didn't think of this case. Is there any way to reformulate the question to eliminate this triviality?

Comment: I thought about that a bit when I commented, and I couldn’t think of one.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott how about for every fixed uncountable family of bases, open sets can be written as countable union of bases selected from the family.

Comment: Your reformulation is just a complicated way of asking for a space which is hereditarily Lindelöf but not Lindelöf.